# How to inverse laplace the following

Tags: laplace-transform

Been stuck on this for a while now and I have an exam tomorrow at 10am and I fear this might come up and it's only inverse laplace I can't do, this is my attempt at it but I know it's wrong..can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm replacing $s+1$ with $s$

$$L^{-1}\frac{(s+1)^{2}}{s^{3}}$$
$$L^{-1}\frac{s^{2}}{s^{3}}|s=s-1$$
$$L^{-1}\frac{1}{s}|s=s-1$$
$$e^{t}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep using this sloppy, confusing notation in multiple questions. Here you don't even want the substitution:

$$\frac{(s+1)^2}{s^3}=\frac{s^2+2s+1}{s^3}=\frac{1}{s}+\frac{2}{s^2}+\frac{1}{s^3}.$$

Now deal with the terms separately.

Comment: Notation that we were shown in class, maybe different to where you're from, thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Modrisco I think it's made more confusing because of how you're TeXing it; adding a space, or using \left and \right to make the bar match the size of the fraction, would help. But even putting that aside, it would be better to use a different letter. About the only time it is a good idea to replace a letter with itself is when you are making a ton of substitutions.